# Error when generating javadoc with eclipse with my "module-info.java"

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

I'm working on a java project with Eclipse. My `module-info.java` contains the following lines of code :

```
module MyVelibGroup13 {
    requires org.junit.jupiter.api;
    requires junit;
}
```

and when generating javadoc with Eclipse (Project > Generate Javadoc) I get :

```
Loading source file C:\Users\Morgan\git\GroupProject13\MyVelibGroup13\src\module-info.java...
C:\Users\Morgan\git\GroupProject13\MyVelibGroup13\src\module-info.java:2: error: module not found: org.junit.jupiter.api
    requires org.junit.jupiter.api;
                              ^
C:\Users\Morgan\git\GroupProject13\MyVelibGroup13\src\module-info.java:3: error: module not found: junit
    requires junit;
             ^
2 errors
```

My code runs withouh any problem, including JUnit tests.

Anyone knows how I can generate the javadoc without this error ?

EDIT : 
I tried adding --add-module to the VM like [this post](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=543405#c2) but it didn't work. I've entered it like this :

Image of the window to generate javadoc:

[image]

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59345591/module-not-found-message-when-generating-javadocs-in-eclipse

Comment: @NitinBisht I just tried but it didn't work, i've edited the post to show it

Comment: Could you take a backup of your .classpath, delete it, close & open eclipse and build your project again and see if that works? .classpath is a file which reside in your project directory.

Comment: @Govind How do I build the project ? I can't click "Build all" in the project tab

Comment: Try to build you Project Explorer

Comment: Try to build your project via Project Explorer and run your junit test to make sure that works and try generating Javadoc

Comment: I have to choose between "Build Path" > "Link Source" or "New Source Folder" when i right click on my project from the project explorer

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `JUnit` to your `BuildPath`. Rightclick your project and select `BuildPath` and then `Configure BuildPath`. Now select `Modulepath` and then `Add Library`. There you can select JUnit.

Another way is to write a `JUnit test`. Eclipse shows you an error and will show you a quickfix where you coul add `JUnit` to your `BuildPath`.

[Select BuildPath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvzVv.png)

[Add JUnit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDxPz.png)

Comment: Not sure if you missplet ```JUnit``` in ```JUnite```. I already had JUnit 5 in my Module Path libraries, tried adding Junit4 but still the same issue.

Comment: You are right sorry. A mate of me had the same problem. He deleted JUnit from build path and added it again. This fixed his problem. If it doesn't fix yours, I am realy sorry.