# 'module not found' error when generating Javadoc

Tags: java, eclipse, module, javadoc, modulenotfounderror

When trying to generate a Javadoc in Eclipse, I get the error `module not found: org.junit.jupiter.api`

All related problems I found on the internet were solved by adding `--add-modules=org.junit.jupiter.api` to the Javadoc VM options. 
Like in this answer ["Module not found" message when generating JavaDocs in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59345591/module-not-found-message-when-generating-javadocs-in-eclipse), I also changed my JAVA_HOME and PATH_TO_FX System Variables (not defined previously). I looked up the normal settings and changed them to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.2` and `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.2\lib` respectively. 
Yet Javadoc still gives the same error. Any idea what is going wrong?

---

This is the entire error message:

```
Loading source file C:\Users\jonas\OneDrive\school\3-Leuven\1ste jaar\OOP\src\pacman\src\module-info.java...
C:\Users\Onedrive\school\3-Leuven\OOP\pacman\src\module-info.java:4: error: module not found: org.junit.jupiter.api
    requires org.junit.jupiter.api;
                              ^
1 error
```

This is my project structure

[image: Project Explorer View]

And here is the module-info.java file

```java
module pacman {
    exports pacman;
    
    requires org.junit.jupiter.api;    //this is where the error happens
}
```

I use Eclipse 2020-12 on a Windows 10 machine.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error, but managed to make it disappear by inserting this snippet in `pom.xml`:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <show>protected</show>
                <failOnError>false</failOnError>  <-- fix
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```